# How can I remove the "highlighting" in a razor file in Intellij Rider?

Tags: razor, blazor, rider

Is there a way to disable the @code highlighting for razor files?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a color scheme preference, that you can easily change in the settings, by disabling `Background` in:

`Editor/Color Scheme/ASP.NET/Razor/Code Block`

[image]